# Js expression showing NaN output

Tags: javascript, angular

The data in coming from My **HTML** file to my **TS** file through 'Two way' binding.

Individual element showing correct output but expression showing output NaN.

My **HTML** Code.

```
<div id="que1">
    <p>What is your estimated savings?</p>
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="quesForm">
        <input ref-filter type="number" formControlName="estimatedsavings" [(ngModel)]="estimatedSavings">
        <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmitQ1()" [disabled]="!filter.value">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="que2">
    <p>What is your combined family income?</p>
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="quesForm">
        <input ref-filtert type="number" formControlName="familyincome" [(ngModel)]="familyIncome">
        <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmitQ4()" [disabled]="!filtert.value">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My **TS** file

```
quesForm: FormGroup;
estimatedSavings:number;
familyIncome:number;

totalSavings:number = (this.estimatedSavings - this.familyIncome); 

onSubmitQ4 = function() {
    console.log(this.childrengoingtoCollege);
    console.log(this.totalSavings);
    console.log(typeof(this.totalSavings));
}
```

Comment: totalSavings is printig as NaN right?

Comment: whatever data you are taking for input that should pars into Int, now this time it is consider as a string that's why showing not a number error (NaN)

Answer (score 1):

`totalSavings` is calculated once in your code by init of your component. This moment `estimatedSavings` and `familyIncome` are `undefined`. You can set default values and use getter instead this way:

.ts file:

```
familyIncome:number = 0;
totalSavings:number = 0;

get totalSavings():number {
   return this.estimatedSavings - this.familyIncome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where the property `childrengoingtoCollage` is from but in this code example it is not set so that might be NaN. The `totalSavings` only get calculated when initialized (where the `estimatedSavings` and `familyIncome` are still `undefined`). Thats why it results in `NaN`. If you type something in the textboxes it gets synced with the variables in the background, but the calculation for `totalSavings` doesnt get executed again.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialize the variables. Set the default value for these
familyIncome:number = 0
totalSavings:number = 0